# Using jQuery UI Puff Hide on a row of a table misbehaves

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table

I have a html `table` and I am trying to use the puff effect in jQuery UI to hide a specific `tr`

Problem is since the effect changes the position and size of the element it is applied on and in a table the position and size of other rows is affected by the position of any row in the table, when the effect plays it also moves the other rows in the table.

Is this a jQuery UI bug? Is there any workaround?

Here's my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class='cart-item'>
         <td><img class='picture' src='1.jpg'></td>
         <td>Product</td>
         <td class='price'>$25</td>
         <td><a class='remove' href='cart/remove/1' name='1'>X</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class='cart-item'>
         <td><img class='picture' src='2.jpg'></td>
         <td>Product</td>
         <td class='price'>$25</td>
         <td><a class='remove' href='cart/remove/2' name='2'>X</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class='cart-item'>
         <td><img class='picture' src='3.jpg'></td>
         <td>Product</td>
         <td class='price'>$25</td>
         <td><a class='remove' href='cart/remove/3' name='3'>X</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(The JavaScript to remove the item is called when the remove button is pressed on each cart item)

My JavaScript:

```
cartItem.hide("puff");
```

(`cartItem` is the `tr` of the cart item to remove)

And the CSS:

```
table {
    width: 90%; 
    margin: 40px;

td {
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some html/javascript sample code goes miles when trying to get a problem solved on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to achieve what you're wanting:

```
$('a.remove').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    cartItem = $(this).closest('tr.cart-item');
    newCartItem = $('<table />').append($(cartItem).clone().wrap('<table></table>'))
    console.log(newCartItem);

    newCartItem.appendTo('body').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': cartItem.offset().top,
        'left': cartItem.offset().left,
        'background-color': 'red'
    });

    cartItem.fadeOut(

    function() {
        newCartItem.hide('puff');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6KEXC/)

This effectively clones the 'cart-item' table-row, appends the clone to a table and then absolutely positions that table over the element you're wanting to remove, runs the 'puff' effect on the temporary/cloned elements and, after completion, hides the element.

It's not quite as smooth as I'd like, but I'm not sure how to improve on that.